# Restrict fields from being changed by json-patch

Tags: json, rest, api-design, json-patch, http-patch

Is there a way to restrict (or only allow) certain fields from being altered by a json-patch method?

Is this even a desired feature of `HTTP PATCH`? I could not find anything (neither positive nor negative) in the respective [rfc-5789 documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)

I'm using https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch within a Spring project, but would like to discuss this independent from the tech-stack. I'm aware that I could just implement this in a custom way by just allowing certain paths in my REST Facade.